# How to Migrate Virtual Machine From One Region to Another Region

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azureportal

On portal.azure.com I am trying to move one of my Linux VM from one region to another region.

How can I perform this task either on UI or on Linux az cli is fine.

Comment: Your VM use managed disk or unmanaged disk?

Comment: For a managed disk, the OS VHD is not in storage account, you should copy it to another region storage account firstly.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an Azure Virtual Machine, there are two services that work in tandem to create this machine: Compute and Storage. On the Storage side, a VHD is created in one of your storage accounts within the Azure Storage Service. The physical node that this VHD is stored on is located in the region you specified to place your Virtual Machine. On the compute side, we find a physical node in a second cluster to place your virtual machine. When the VM starts in that cluster, it establishes a connection with the Storage Service and boots from the VHD. When creating a Virtual Machine, we require that the VHD be located in a storage account in the same region where you are creating the VM. This is to ensure there is performance consistency when communicating between the Virtual Machine and the storage account.

**Workaround steps to migrate the virtual machine from one region to another:**

1. Stop the Virtual Machine
2. Copy the VHD blob from a storage account in the source region to a storage account in the destination region.
3. Create an Azure Disk from the blob
4. Boot the Virtual Machine from the Disk

You may refer “[Migrate Azure Virtual Machines between Storage Accounts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/migrate-azure-virtual-machines-between-storage-accounts/)”.

Comment: After creating Azure Disk you need to create a VM, where we can add virtual networks. 
Refer: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/143984-migrate-azure-virtual-machine-to-different-location-region